# Javascript ajax success function fires off multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my project, I'm working on a function which deletes rows from a table and also from the database using `.ajax()`. I've created my function for when the user clicks on the delete button. As you can understand, there a several rows and every row has its own delete button.

Now, when the user clicks on one of them for the first time, a popup modal appears with the question if he/she is sure about deleting the item. When he/she clicks yes, the popup disappears and the row fades-out. This all works perfectly, but...

When you click on a second delete button **without** refreshing the page, JavaScript fires off the current requested delete (and `id`) + de previous one. If you do it for a third time, it will fire of the current one and the two previous ones.

I tried to empty the current `var $(this).attr('data-page-id');`, but it still does the same thing when the `.ajax()` success function gets fired.

```
$('a.btn-page-delete').click(function() {

    var curPageId = $(this).attr('data-page-id');

    $('#delete-page').modal('show');

    $('a#action-confirm').click(function() {

        $.ajax({

            type       : 'POST',
            url        : '/pages/async/delete',
            dataType   : 'json',
            data       : { page : curPageId },
            success    : function(data) {

                $('#delete-page').modal('hide');

                console.log(curPageId);
                console.log(data);

            },
            error   : function() {}

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: I assume you see this behaviour because *every time* a row is deleted, you **add a new** click event handler to `a#action-confirm`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your *outer* click event handler gets called

```
$('a.btn-page-delete').click(function() {
```

it'll `.bind()` another click event handler to `$('a#action-confirm')` everytime. So, everytime the outer event is executed you add one more event handler.

I'm sure you can and should re-build and construct this in a better way, but in the present state your only choice is to `.unbind()` / `.off()` the inner click handlers, like

```
 $('a#action-confirm').off('click').click(function() {
```

that will remove any click event handler bound via jQuery previously.

Ref.: [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: Yeah, it worked... but how would you build it. I mean, this is pretty 'OK' code right? Thanks anyway!

Comment: dp == display pic == avatar. (dp is taken from a social networking website 'orkut'. It was quite famous in India). I remember you hadnt any pic before.

Comment: @Wimbjorno: well I'm not fully aware of the underlaying principle (DOM/Gui wise), but I guess I would do it either with a closure or I would make sure that a user is just not able to click a second time on the outer element. Either by disabling it or having modal overlays.